# Trying to get file name and line number from editor on right click menu option Visual Studio 2015 Add-In: SDK, API…

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, add-in, visual-studio-sdk

I have been trying to get the current line number and file name of the text/code editor window on a right click function. However for the life of me I can not work out where it gets the current line number or file name context from...

I currently have a right click menu option. Now all I really need this to do is tell me where the click was (AKA the line number, possibly the col number and the filename)

I have searched around but cant seem to find anything anywhere which allows this easily. I know it's possible just not how to do it...

```
    public void MenuItemClickLogicFeedback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogWindow dialog = new AddEditLineFeedbackForm(model)
        {
            Width = 310,
            Height = 315,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen
        };

        var result = dialog.ShowModal();
    }
```

I basically need to pass in the line number and file name into the popup from the position the menu was clicked at... (Seems really simple hey...) :/

Thanks in Advance to anyone who helps :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it in the end...

IVsTextView allows you to get the current position soo..
IVsTextView.GetCaretPos(out line, out column); is what allows it

Was that simple...

For the file name I used ITextDocument
Soo ITextDocument.FilePath returns what I required...

Easy in the end when you find the right modern interface, and not some old DTE Interface which said it could do it :D